# How do I remove this plastic shower drain cover?

Tags: shower, drain, plastic, cover

My shower has recently been having trouble draining and, with a flashlight, I've noticed that there's a great deal of hair and other material stuck in the pipe, clogging it. It seems simple enough to remove the clog, if only I were able to first remove the drain cover.

It appears that the cover is cemented in place and I can't find any hints on how to properly remove it. I tried using pliers to grab it and either twist it out or pull it, but it's definitely not coming out.

Is there something I'm missing? Is there a way to remove it easily? Or should I just force it out, possibly breaking it in the process (it's already cracked, as you can see in the picture)? What sort of replacement should I look for, and how do I install it?

[image: plastic shower drain cover]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That appears to be intended to pry out with a screwdriver or similar flat tool at the indents a little past 6 o'clock and a little past 12 o'clock as pictured.

Comment: There isn't much room for a screwdriver between the grout and the cover, even at the indents. The plastic is also so brittle feeling that I imagine it'd just shatter if I applied much leverage. I tried pulling it straight off with the pliers again, this time with a good deal more force. Surprisingly it came off, and there didn't appear to be anything in particular gluing it down.